# How to add firebase to android project with Google Play Services 14.x

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I want to add firebase to my react-native project.
As the [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/android/setup) says it needs a device running Google Play services 15.0.0 or later.

I have a device which has Google Play Services version 14.7.99 and it is the latest version for my device. (As i understood Google Play Services latest version differs from device to device)

So is there a way to use firebase in devices with Google Play Services version 14?

Thx in advance

Comment: which part of the documentation that you quoted that answers your question with a "no" is not clear?

Comment: @Tim i want to know if there is a solution like downgrading firebase or google-services library which can work with older devices.

Comment: You might want to give version `12.x` of the Firebase SDKs a go. See https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#20180328

Answer (score 1):

As it quite clearly states in the documentation

> A device running:
>
> - Android 4.1 (API level 14, Jelly Bean) or later
> - Google Play services 15.0.0 or later

If your device cannot run Google Play Services 15.0.0 or later then there is no way to get Firebase to run on that device.